# Asana API get all tags

Tags: api, tags, asana

I'm the developer of this PHP class wrapper for Asana API https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class

In the last Asana API update, tags support were added. I added all the endpoints to my class but I found that one isn't working. This one:
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags

It returns me HTTP code 0...

That fails too:

```
curl -u API_KEY: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags
```

Everything is working, get tags by workspace, add tags to task, etc.

But that doesn't and documentation says it should work.

[image: API Tags Documentation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

This appears to work on Asana's end. If you are logged-in to Asana, try putting that URL in your browser.

HTTP status code 0 is not something that is returned from the API. More than likely that is just a code on your HTTP client to indicate that the server never returned a response. It is possible that you have a large number of tags so the response takes too long or is too large, but we have seen this particular request return hundreds of tags successfully.

Perhaps you have a very short timeout or some other connection problem?

Comment: Today it worked but it takes really long to respond, I don't know why because all other petitions take no more than 1 second to respond and this one lasts for 8-10 seconds. I have around 30 tags... I don't think they are too many...

Comment: Yes, there are definitely places where the API has performance issues. It is helpful to provide feedback about these so that the team can address and prioritize performance work going forward.